# Override DrawItem of ComboBox

Tags: c#, inheritance, combobox, controls, ondraw

I changed the highlight color of various of the controls, and I am planning to make more changes. So I though is better to create my own controls and reuse them instead of making the changed for each and every one of them.

I created a new user control, and inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`.
The problem is I cannot find a way to override `onDraw` like I would for `onClick`.

So how I would go and override it? Here is the code I used for each control `onDraw` event

```
public void comboMasterUsers_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Brush brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ?
                      Brushes.LightSeaGreen : new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);

        g.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboMasterUsers.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font,
                 new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public class myCombo : ComboBox
{
    // expose properties as needed
    public Color SelectedBackColor{ get; set; }

    // constructor
    public myCombo()
    {
        DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(DrawCustomMenuItem);
        DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        SelectedBackColor= Color.LightSeaGreen;
    }

    protected  void DrawCustomMenuItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
         // a dropdownlist may initially have no item selected, so skip the highlighting:
        if (e.Index >= 0) 
        {  
          Graphics g = e.Graphics;
          Brush brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ?
                         new SolidBrush(SelectedBackColor) : new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);
          Brush tBrush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);

          g.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
          e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font,
                     tBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
          brush.Dispose();
          tBrush.Dispose();
        }
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

You may consider exposing more Properties as you expand your customziation, so you can change them for each instance when you want to..

Also don't forget to dispose GDI objects you create, like brushes and pens!

**Edit:** Just noticed that `BackColor` would hide the original property. Changed it to `SelectedBackColor`, which actually says what it is!

**Edit 2:** As Simon noted in the comments, there is a `HasFlag` method and so as of .Net 4.0 one can also write:

```
      Brush brush = ((e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected) ?
```

which is a little clearer and shorter.

**Edit 3:** Actually for drawing onto controls the use of `TextRenderer.DrawText` is recommended over `graphics.DrawString`..

Comment: Thanks, it works. But there is one problem. When I change the DropDownStyle to DropDownList, there is an error:
InvalidArgument =value of -1 is not valid for index

Comment: see my small correction wrt tBrush! GDI objects have a hideous tendency to silently leak..

Comment: And another small correction ;-) I didn't notice the warning but now it looks OK..

Comment: To make a long, sad story short: Brushes, Pens and Bitmaps are special. They are not normal c# objects, which the GC collects; they are stored separately and it is your responsibilty to dispose of them. A GDI heritage from the 90s..

Comment: In .Net 4 and above, I think it is cleaner to write "e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected)" instead of "e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected"

Comment: Instead of disposing the Brushes you could use the using(...) clause. All your background drawing with SelectedBackColor and FillRectangle() is unnecessary because this is already done in e.DrawBackground();

Comment: Instead of "this.Items[e.Index].ToString()" use :
`var svalue = string.Empty;
var pi = Items[e.Index].GetType().GetProperty(DisplayMember);
if (pi != null)
    svalue = pi.GetValue(Items[e.Index]).ToString();`

Comment: Get item text: `string svalue = this.GetItemText(SelectedItem);`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this helpful post. I made one small enhancement that others may find useful.

When the ComboBox has its DisplayMember property set to access a specific property of the displayed items, ToString() may not give the expected text. The fix for this is to use:

```
    GetItemText(Items[e.Index])
```

to retrieve the required text in the call to DrawString().

Answer (score 0):

It will useful for someone who looking for VB.net

Public Class myCombo

```
Inherits ComboBox

Public Property SelectedBackColor As Color

Public Sub New()
    AddHandler DrawItem, New DrawItemEventHandler(AddressOf DrawCustomMenuItem)
    DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
    DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
End Sub

Protected Sub DrawCustomMenuItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs)
    If e.Index < 0 Then
        Return
    End If
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
    Dim Cb As ComboBox = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)
    If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.OrangeRed), e.Bounds) ' selected item background color
    Else
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.White), e.Bounds) ' background color
    End If
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Cb.Items(e.Index).ToString(), e.Font, New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor),
                          New Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y), StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
End Sub
```

End Class