# Change combobox items color if condition is met

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, combobox

I'm about to set an appointement management system, so i have a combobox with every hour of the day (08:00, 08:15; 08:30 ... 18:00).

I want to highlate all hours booked by changing color of combobox item, i'm planning to use sql query select and count to know if a specific hour is already choosen.

Can you please help to find a link between select and color change of combobox ?

Comment: What UI are you using? WinForms, WPF, web? Please add the appropriate tag and remove `visual-studio` because the question is not visual studio related.

Comment: @Steeeve i'm using winform application

Comment: Does [Override DrawItem of ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475812/override-drawitem-of-combobox) help?

Comment: You can set the DataSource of you ComboBox to a `List<class>`, where the class objects contains information about the Colors to use in specified range of values, set `DrawMode = OwnerDrawFixed` (or `OwnerDrawVariable`, depending on the use case) and draw the ComboBox Item's background and foreground color based on the current Item's values. Or draw an icon that represents the status. Here's an example: [Combobox draw image on selected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103139/7444103)

Comment: Or enable / disable items; here another example: [Disabling a ComboBox Item based on a CheckBox state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56992518/7444103) -- Or add more information, with mixed graphics and text. See [ComboBox OwnerDrawVariable Font format size problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103375/7444103), for example.